# Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment doesn't validate nested resource

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm

I'm looking to incorporate Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment into a build pipeline so I know before deployment that the template / parameters has got any major problems.

However I'm finding if I used [nested deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) it provides no validation to the nested deployment whatsoever, I can have a bad templateLink -> uri with incorrect variables even in the URI and it's still validating as successful.

I have tried with a local template, a template uri, with/without hashed parameters and parameters file just in case.

I assume underneath the AzureRM powershell is using the [Resource Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/validate), it doesn't hint to what the validate actually does with nested templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/validate

Anything I've missed? Any suggestions on how to validate the entire template, do I need to parse the nested templates and some how re-construct the parameters from json and do the sub-deployments by hand (which would be a shame)?

Comment: can you share your code where you invoke the cmdlet?

Comment: Thanks @MartinBrandl looks like I've managed to crack it.

Comment: I saw it and already upvoted your answer - thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a forum post from a Microsoft Employee in the Resource Manager team (a private forum so unfortunately cannot provide a link), it appears Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment does "template expansion" which as 4c74356b41 has also kindly pointed out - surely the nested template validation should work...

So further experimentation has led to finding a limitation in the validation, see below for an example. If there is a variable missing entirely in a nested deployment it doesn't appear to be picked up as a validation warning in the parent template, and also appears to interfere with the template expansion leading to the nested template to be ignored also.

If `"parameters": { "missing" :  "[variables('PURPOSEFULLY_MISSING')]"  }` is removed then the template is validated as normal and the nested template also.

Snippet of the overall template for just the nested resources:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('deploymentName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('deploymentUri')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": { "missing" :  "[variables('PURPOSEFULLY_MISSING')]"  }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: this is pretty interesting

Comment: Ah ha, of course I do have another syntax issue here it should of been:

`"parameters": { "missing" : { "value": "[variables('PURPOSEFULLY_MISSING')]" }`

Which I'm sure would of compounded the issue, but either way it's interesting it can give erroneous results.

Answer (score 2):

that is not true, it will validate nested deployment even if you gate it with `condition: false`, so you are doing something wrong, we would need to look at the template and how you are calling the cmdlet to understand whats going on

as to the validation: there is no real way to validate the deployment works (test-azurermresourcegroupdeployment is just garbage, extremely low value). the only way to validate it - deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, agreed Test.. doesn't seem hugely useful, but a good first gate perhaps. There are so many schemas incomplete that JSON/schema validation isn't useful either. I'll likely investigate some of the ingeious options found in blog posts which intercept the debug messages to validate resource deployment, but something for another day.